# How set options from HIGHCHARTS in a chart using vue chartkick

Tags: vue.js, highcharts, chartkick

I am using this library: [chartkick](https://www.chartkick.com/vue) for load charts with vue, and need a chart bar with scroll how in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/vk5afgwo/1/). From HIGHTCHART. But i can´t set options to component in chartkick. I try set with `:library` in component but no work.

Component:

```
<bar-chart :data="chartData.bar" :library="chartOptions"></bar-chart>
```

Data:

```
data() {
  return {
    chartData: {
      bar: [],
      colors: [this.colors]
    },
    chartOptions:{
      xAxis: {
        scrollbar: {
          enabled: true
        },
      },
    },
  }
},
```

Comment: scroll down at [chartkick](https://www.chartkick.com/vue) page, then you will see how to set option.

Comment: I'm having this same issue and the link doesn't help. All it shows is passing `:library="{backgroundColor:...}"`, but it doesn't explain how the `library` attribute gets merged with different options for the various charting libraries making it almost impossible to get the desired effect. I'm trying to disable animations on HighCharts and I've tried about 20 things including `:library="{chart:{animation:false}}"`, `:library="{plotOptions:{line:{animation:false}}}"`, etc

Comment: The scrollbar is only available inside Highstock, in Highcharts you can use `chart.scrollablePlotArea`: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.scrollablePlotArea

Answer (score -1):

Please try with this option. Add this in your global js.(Main.js)

```
Chartkick.options = {
    xAxis: {
        scrollbar: {
            enabled: true
        },
    },
}
```